# Position index goes higher then the list count

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem.
CoinPriceLayout.RemoveAllViewsInLayout();

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var coin in coinList)
{                 
    var view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.LiveCoinPrice, CoinPriceLayout, false);
    TextView LiveCoinName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCoinName);
    TextView LiveCoinPrice = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCoinPrice);
    LiveCoinName.Text = coin.Coin;
    LiveCoinPrice.Text = coin.Price.ToString();

    Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        CoinPriceLayout.AddView(view, index);
    });

    index += 1;
}
```

You don't need to understand all the variables but it get's 3 coins with the correct price. Then I add foreach coin a layout to display on the screen and when it got an update it deletes all the views and build it again. Now this code runs the first time right, but the second time it crashes on this line:

```
CoinPriceLayout.AddView(view, index);
```

With the error:

> Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=3 count=0

Now the only difference is that the second time it goes into that code, it runs with a background worker. But I don't understand why it runs the first time correct.

I run the background thread like this:

```
System.Threading.Timer CoinPrice_Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(LoadCoins), null, 1000, 1000);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to add a view in the `CoinPriceLayout` at the position 3. But you have cleared this layout's children using `RemoveAllViewsInLayout` then the out of index error occurs as there are no other views in this layout. The index should be 0.

You can try to make a breakpoint at `CoinPriceLayout.AddView(view, index);` and check the index's value. Did you forget to reset the index value to 0?

**Updates**

The second time you call the `LoadCoins` at a background thread, so `index += 1;` won't wait

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    CoinPriceLayout.AddView(view, index);
});
```

It will go to 2 directly when you want to add views at index 0. This causes the issue. So you'd better place the `index += 1;` in the `RunOnUiThread`:

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    CoinPriceLayout.AddView(view, index);
    index++;
});
```

Comment: It does not get reset, but I am resetting the index to 0 at the top of the code I gave you?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I've seen that. But the exception says you are adding at 3. Maybe you change it somewhere else. So try to add a breakpoint to check the index's value.

Comment: I changed the name to something unique, but still nothing. it doesn;t get used somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but why was index 3 then. If it doesn't get raised it had to stay 0 right?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk The foreach loop runs on the thread but AddView is on main. The `index += 1;` will run three times immediately and the index goes to 3. At last the main thread fires the `AddView` method.